# Calling Fragment from an activity and updating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a main activity and i am using this activity to make a call to the fragment log off.  The problem i am facing is i can't remove the layout of the activity from the background even though i am in the fragment. So in this case, i see both the activity layout and on top of that i see the fragment layout.  I just want to remove the calling activity layout from the fragment.How do i accomplish this?

My main screen looks like this:[image]

and my logoff screen looks like this: 
[image]

my main screen layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FFCC00"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llProfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:visibility="gone">



        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
             <!--   android:layout_weight="2" -->

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                   <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="321dp"
            android:layout_height="142dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how i am calling the fragment:

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
private ListView drawerListView;
private String[] navMenuTitles;

fragment = new LogOffFragment(mGoogleApiClient);
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerListView.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
}
```

onCreateView of the fragment looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logoff, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Show teh codez! ... More specifically, what is the layout of your main activity and how are you loading the fragment?

Comment: adding the main layout file and the code for fragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments live inside activities by nature. But you have a few options.

1. Set a solid background on your fragment, so you don't see the activity
2. Hide the activity layout
3. Put your logout functionality into an activity instead of a fragment
4. Take your current activity content and put it into a fragment instead. Then let your activity have a container to host the fragments, and replace the contents with the logout fragment when needed.

Comment: I am getting inclined towards option 3 but before i make the changes i will wait for more replies..